# Imprimir un archivo png automáticamente a mi impresora

Tags: java

estoy realizando un programa que me crea un archivo png. El archivo me lo hace correctamente, y me lo guarda en un directorio.
La cuestión es que necesito imprimir este archivo automáticamente a mi impresora predeterminada he probado varios como el desktop.print pero no funciona.

```
private static void imprimir(File codi){
        java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT)){
        try {
        try{
        String nombreImpresora = "Brother DCP-1610W series Printer"; //dato a modificar segun la impresora
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n \""+nombreImpresora+"\"");
        System.out.println("Imprimiendo");
        }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error al ejecutar el comando. Error: "+ex);
        }
        desktop.print(codi);
        } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print("El sistema no permite imprimir usando la clase Desktop");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }else{
        System.out.print("El sistema no permite imprimir usando la clase Desktop");
        }
    }
```

Esa es la función que utilizo, pasando como parámetro el archivo png. Alguna sugerencia ?

Answer (score 0):

Por fin conseguí el código por si os interesa.

```
public static void imprimirDirecto(String url, int i) {
             FileInputStream archivo; 
            try { 
             archivo =new FileInputStream(url);  
             DocFlavor formato = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG; 
             Doc documento = new SimpleDoc(archivo, formato, null);  
             PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

            //----las opciones que me interesan configurar de la impresora
            aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);//el tamaño de la hoja (carta)
           // aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
            aset.add(new Copies(1));
            //aset.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);
           // aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT); 
            // discover the printers that can print the format according to the
            // instructions in the attribute set
            PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(formato, aset);
            // Create a print job from one of the print services
            if (services.length > 0) { 
                    DocPrintJob job = services[i].createPrintJob(); 
                    try { 
                            job.print(documento, aset); 
                    } catch (PrintException pe) {} 
            } 
            }catch(Exception e){
            }  
        }
```